# Display line chart with data retrieved from database using morris.js, PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, morris.js

I am working with a Bootstrap 4 template that uses morris.js for charts. I have a database that I am trying to retrieve data from and the issue is that it not being displayed dynamically on the chart.

I already worked on the query and tried to echo it in the file morris.js. I have tried solutions found on stack overflow, but I couldn't see where the issue is.

This is the index.php:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="header">
     <h2>line Chart</h2>
 </div>
   <div class="body">
     <div id="m_area_chart"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is the MySQL query:

Sample data in table `tbl_water_level`

| ID | date | dev_eui | water_level | battery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-18 08:06:44 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-10-18 09:06:44 | 2 | 12 | 3 |

```
$sql3 = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as `period`, water_level as water_level, battery as battery FROM `tbl_water_level` WHERE `date` > SUBDATE( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
order by date";
$result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
$chart_data = '';
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
 $chart_data .= "{ period:'".$row3["period"]."', water_level:".$row3["water_level"].", battery:".$row3["battery"]." }, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
```

The SELECT query is ok. But, there could be an issue with the while statement. Also, it is not throwing any error so far. I run the query and this is what it returned:
`[{"time":"13:45","water_level":"0.25","battery":"0"}]`

My question is, how do I get the X-axis to display the `time` and the two graph lines to show `water_level` and `battery`.

This is the file morris.js: Please note that **period** on the x-axis is years(2000,2001,2002,etc.) initially displayed. I think it is already calculated in another JS file. I kept xkey as period, since in the MySQL query I put in the array.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
new Morris.Area({
 element : 'm_area_chart',
 data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
 xkey:'period',
 ykeys:['water_level', 'battery'],
 labels:['water_level', 'battery'],
 hideHover:'auto',
  pointSize: 2,
 fillOpacity: 0,
 pointStrokeColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#5dcef6', '#c0d0d6'],
 behaveLikeLine: true,
 gridLineColor: '#eeeeee',
 lineWidth: 1,
 lineColors: ['#2cbfb7', '#5dcef6', '#c0d0d6'],
 resize: true
 

});
});
</script>
```

This is the graph I am expecting to be displayed(I tweaked the X-axis to put time so that we could see what I want):

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MttyG.jpg)

**Update**

I was able to get to it to work. The solution was to add the script into the file `index.php`. I also changed the date format to `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'` in the SELECT query. This was the solution given by user1191247. I have updated the query and script as required in my question.

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this code? Is this a PHP problem, a MySQL problem, or a JS problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase This is partly a MySQL problem. The query is ok but the there could be an issue with the while statement.  For the JS, I am definitely making a confusion between xkey and ykeys. Atleast, for the xkey I called ```time``` as ```period``` in the query.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What **exactly** is not working with the given query? It does not look that complicated. Also, keep in mind that `json_encode` works better than manually writing a JSON encoded string

Comment: DO NOT try to assemble JSON data manually in string form - cumbersome & error-prone. Populate the corresponding data structure in PHP, and then use `json_encode` to _get_ a JSON representation of it.

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase. I edited my question.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not generate **static** markup that generates the expected graph first, and then integrate the data from MySQL? That's what was suggested one week ago in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77322775/display-line-chart-with-data-retrieved-from-mysql-database

Comment: @NicoHaase, The other graph was much simpler and did not involve JS. I am definitely stuck with the script in the file morris.js. I don't understand how to display the timestamp in the attribute `xkey`. I have tried to generate the static markup, but the issue is that xkey which is has the value period (2000,2001,2002,etc) is already calculated in another JS. And it could not be converted to time

Comment: If you're unable to generate **static** markup that generates this graph, it's uesless to try to involve PHP here. That only makes your attempts more difficult

Comment: The issue is the `xkey`. It is displayed as years and cannot be converted into timestamp. No hope?

Comment: What do you mean by "no hope"? What **exactly** is the issue? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: Please add a small sample of the data in `tbl_water_level` (as a markdown or ascii table). Your x-axis labelling looks a little strange as it isn't linear.

Comment: @user1191247 I have added a sample of the data in my question. And yes, the graph is not linear.

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm trying. I will edit my question as soon as I progress. Thanks

Comment: I found the solution. Please see my updated question. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) lists the following in the description for the `xkey` option:

> A string containing the name of the attribute that contains date (X) values.
>
> Timestamps are accepted in the form of millisecond timestamps (as returned by `Date.getTime()` or as strings in the following formats:
>
> - `2012`
> - `2012 Q1`
> - `2012 W1`
> - `2012-02`
> - `2012-02-24`
> - `2012-02-24 15:00`
> - `2012-02-24 15:00:00`
> - `2012-02-24 15:00:00.000`

If you select your data from the db in the format you intend to use (column aliased as `period` instead of `time`), then you can pass the full result set direct to json_encode:

```php
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pass', 'test', 3306);
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
$db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);

$sql = <<<'SQL'
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') AS period, water_level, battery
    FROM tbl_water_level
    WHERE `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
    ORDER BY `date` ASC;
    SQL;

$result = $db->query($sql);
$chart_data = json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Your question suggests that your js file is being parsed by PHP, so you can populate the data option. This is a really bad idea and partially defeats the point of having js in separate files. You can assign the JSON to a js global variable or a data attribute of the chart div, then your js file can be treated as the static asset it should be.

You replied in the comments that your *"graph is not linear"*. Time is linear and graphing time series data with a non-linear scale does not make sense, in this case at least. If you really want your graph to be non-linear you can add `parseTime: false` to your options:

> Set to `false` to skip time/date parsing for X values, instead treating them as an equally-spaced series.

Comment: I was able to show the time on the X-axis by changing the date format to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i` in the SELECT query.

Comment: Please let me know if I should mark your answer as correct, because this was part of the solution of what was expected to make the graph to work. Thanks!

Comment: That's entirely up to you. If it helped you get to your desired result then accepting an answer is always appreciated. Alternatively, if you got what you wanted in a different way, you can always answer your own question.